# How to generate IPv6 from EUI64-prefix and MAC address with php

Tags: php, ipv6

I need a script that generates an IPv6 address in php. The given variables that I know are an EUI64-prefix and the MAC address of the device. With these I need to generate an v6 address. The device has no v4 address to generate the addresses from. 
The mac and the prefix are devided trough ":" like "ba:76:1b:ba:62:cb".

Comment: public static function mac($prefix, $mac) {
    // Expand mac address
    $mac = str_replace(['.', '-', ':'], '', $mac);
    $mac = dechex(hexdec($mac) ^ 1 << 41);
    $mac = substr($mac, 0, 5) . 'fffe' . substr($mac, 5);

    // Expand IP address
    $ip = unpack('n*', inet_pton($prefix));
    $ip = implode('', array_map(function ($b) { return sprintf('%04x', $b); }, $ip));

    for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($mac); $i ++) {
        $ip[strlen($ip) - $i] = $mac[strlen($mac) - $i];
    }

    return wordwrap($ip, 4, ':', true);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 4291, IPv6 Addressing Architecture, Appendix A, Creating Modified EUI-64 Format Interface Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#appendix-A), Details how to build an IPv6 address from the MAC address.

You use the network portion of the address (first 64 bits), and create an Interface ID (last 64-bits) using the MAC address.

To create the Interface ID, take the 48 bits in the MAC address, split it into two 24-bit parts, insert the hex value `FFFE` in the middle, and invert the value of the universal/local bit.

Comment: my result in php is now:

`$mac = "ba:76:1b:ba:62:cb";
$prefix = "fda1:384a:74de:"
  
$mac_array = explode(":", $mac);
$host_id = ":".$mac_array[0].$mac_array[1].":".$mac_array[2]."ff:fe".$mac_array[3].":".$mac_array[4].$mac_array[5];
$ipv6 = $prefix."0".$host_id;`

Comment: Are you flipping the U/L bit (the 7th bit of your `$mac_array[0]`)?

Comment: The above did work for me but i dont know how "clean"  the Mac is that i get because it is pregenerated in a was that i do not know

Comment: The MAC is a the BIA in your NIC. Unless someone overrode that, it is clean on every NIC. If you are looking at an already generated IPv6 address, it may be that it was a randomly generated address that Windows and some Linux versions do. There is a way to disable that and use only the SLAAC generated version using the MAC.